# Startup of desktop environment is geting progresively slower over time

Tags: startup, performance, desktop-environments

I have ubuntu 18.04 installed for >3 years with Xfce desktop environment.
Over the last year the startup of desktop environment (i.e. time from log-in before disk finish crunching) became untolerably long (>5minutes?).

This is strange because

1. I expect linux does not have the same issues as Windows which slow it down over time
   ([Windows gets progressively slower over time, why doesn't Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84068/windows-gets-progressively-slower-over-time-why-doesnt-ubuntu))
2. Xfce environment should be most light-weight of all desktop environments.

My ideas what could be the cause:

- I'm pretty sure the slow down has something to do with some disk operations, because the disk crunch terribly.
- I also think it has something to do with some internet app, because I'm unable to load any web page before the disk finishes to crunch.
- I was thinking the issue was due to dropbox sync. Really wen I switch of dropbox the startup is significantly faster. But it is not all, even without dropbox it takse lot of time.
- I would like to investigate what exactly does this huge ammaunt of disk I/O operations in internet access at startup. But I don't know how to do it, especially when the system is a bit frozen and interaction is lagging.

I have read many general articles how to speed up linux startup, e.g. [this](https://itsfoss.com/speed-up-ubuntu-1310/).
But it is to unspecific.

**Question:**

- How to investigate what exact app takes most of disk I/O and internet access operations at startup of desktop environment?
- Are there some processes (e.g. file indexing for search, pre-loading shard libraries ...) which can become more and more demanding a as system gets older (with more files and programs to manage) ? I would like to turn of all such processes.

Comment: This might happen if your HDD is dying. Install GNOME disk and check the disk health. https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/disk-check.html.en

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the most likely cause of this is an accumulation of `snap`s you  might have installed over the years. Try

```
$ snap list
```

to see what they are.

---

In general, to see which processes are (currently) doing a lot of I/O, you can use `iotop`. To see what's using a lot of RAM, you can use `htop` and then `F6` ("SortBy") `PERCENT_MEM`.